# How to identify Shopify App page with no template

Tags: shopify, liquid

Throughout my liquid files, I see lots of conditional statements based on the current template, like this:

```
{% if template contains "product" %}
  (do something)
{% endif %}
```

But I have an app installed that created it's own page:

```
MyStoreName.com/apps/store-locator
```

- which uses no template.

I need to add some code to my theme.liquid file which only executes on this app page.  Is there any other way to identify the page?

Answer (score 1):

Does the page have a title that Shopify can spit out using `{{ page_title }}`? If so, you should be able to do

```
{% if page_title == 'store-locator' %}
    {% code goes here %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the app doesn't give me any options to set the page title.  I'm not sure where it's getting it from, but it's just using my store name.  If I use `{% if page_title | escape == shop.name | escape %}`, it seems to work for now, but there's still the possibility that another page could be auto-generated with the same title.

Comment: I just realized that my client is paying $7/month for this app which is just a google map with some pins.  Maybe my best bet would be to set up my own google map code on a regular page so I can have more control.